# Name for this type of parser, OR why it doesn't exist

Tags: parsing

Conventional parsers consume their entire input and produce a single parse tree.  I'm looking for one that consumes a continuous stream and produces a parse forest [*edit: see discussion in comments regarding why this use of that term may be unconventional*].  My gut says that I can't be the first person to need (or *think* I need) such a parser, but I've searched off and on for months to no avail.

I recognize that I may be ensnared by the XY problem.  My ultimate purpose is to parse a stream of text, ignoring most of it, and produce a stream of parse trees from the sections that are recognized.

So my question is conditional: if a class of parsers with these characteristics exists, **what is it called?**  And if not, **why not?**  What is the alternative?  Perhaps I'm missing some way I can make conventional parsers do what I want.

Comment: Basically your parser parses a single document and yields a parse tree, then immediately starts parsing another document, etc. I suppose this behavior modification is trivial compared to the variety of parsing techniques applied to a single document. Hence the lack of a special term for it.

Comment: I did a Google Search for "Parse Forest," and discovered that the [Earley Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) produces them.

Comment: Incremental parsers are something to look into, which do things similar to what you describe.

Comment: Can those sections overlap?

Comment: Are you possibly looking for *monadic parser combinators* -- that is, a larger parser composed of several smaller parsers.  They are handy for situations where an "island" of one language is embedded in another. My former colleague on the C# design team Luke Hoban has a good article on them: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/08/19/monadic-parser-combinators-using-c-3-0.aspx

Comment: As far as I know, some idiosyncrasies in LaTeX and CSS caused by the fact that they are consumed line-by-line and the parser doesn't "know" what will come later in the file. While I don't know how they work internally, maybe it's worth looking at them.

Comment: There is some confusion. Do you mean that you want a parse tree for
each document in your stream, and that they form together a parse
forest. That is not the usual meaning of parse forest. A parse forest
is a set of parse trees for a single ambiguous document (simplifying a
bit) that can be parsed in different ways. And that is what all
answers are about. Is your stream composed of many complete documents
separated by garbage, or is it a single document that has been partly
garbled. Are your document supposed to be syntactically correct or
not? The proper technical answer depend on that.

Comment: @babou If that's so, then my unconventional use of that term might explain why I couldn't find anything. :)  Yes, my stream is a series of complete documents separated by garbage, and by "parse forest" I meant a collection of trees representing different documents.

Comment: Then forget all the answers about parse forests, and Earley, GLR,
Marpa, derivatives. They are not apparently what you want unless
another reason shows up. Are your documents syntactically correct?
Some parsing technique can recreate context for partially garbled
documents. Do you have a precise syntax for these documents. Is it the
same one for all? Do you really want the parse trees, or would you be
satisfied by isolating the documents, and possibly parse them later,
separately. I think I know what could improve your processing, but I
am not sure you can get that off the shelf.

Comment: The "documents" are predictable text patterns associated with numbers that I want to extract.  Many are just a single word or phrase followed by a number.  In a few cases, I want to recognize documents with a little more structure.  E.g., `foo 42: bar=5 baz=99` might be one document which is-a `foo` and has some properties.  There are many different kinds of documents in the stream.

Comment: This is getting interesting. Do you have a systematic definition of
these patterns? Is it with a grammar (what type)? Could you give a
small part of the definition, which I suppose is used by your
parser. BTW, what kind of parser do you use?  And would you have a
small document meeting that definition.  Sorry for the many questions.

Comment: I designed the lexer generator, and the parser is a hand-written implementation of an interface (in the Java keyword sense) that is generated along with the lexer.  Here are my [token definitions](https://github.com/kjkrum/WeaponM/blob/master/src/main/jplex/DataLexer.jplex). Look at line 93 for a simple example.  The `expr` defines the token, and the `event` names the parser method that will be called with the matching text.  But my lexer generator is buggy and quite difficult to work with, so I'm looking around again for an existing solution or a better understanding of how to make this work.

Comment: Sorry. Did not get any message that you had replied. Better to use
@babou. I am reading, but will be busy soon. - - - - The rules do not
seem recursive. Are they ? Can you make a list of all the words or
ponctuation, parents, etc. that can be at the very beginning of a
document (it does not matter if many). Rather than advance one
character at a time, you could go for the next occurrence of a word
that is a document starter. That can be real fast.

Comment: That's sort of what it does.  The parser advances through the input until it encounters a matching pattern, and throws away garbage in its innermost loop.  The patterns aren't recursive, but the `Rule` patterns can include the `Macro` patterns.  It's kind of interesting but not that great.

Comment: Well, I put my conclusions in an answer. But if you want more ... Thanks you for your patience with my questions.

Comment: Is my contribution any help? The remaining point would be the automatic production of the regex. That should be possible, but I do not understand the tables well enough to do it. What tool is it for?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A parser that returns a (partial) result before the whole input has been consumed is called an *incremental parser*. Incremental parsing can be difficult if there are local ambiguities in a grammar that are only decided later in the input. Another difficulty is feigning those parts of the parse tree that haven't been reached yet.

A parser that returns a forest of all possible parse trees – that is, returns a parse tree for each possible derivation of an ambiguous grammar – is called … I'm not sure if these things have a name yet. I know that the [Marpa parser generator](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html) is capable of this, but any Earley or GLR based parser should be able to pull this off.

---

However, you don't seem to want any of that. You have a stream with multiple embedded documents, with garbage in between:

```
 garbagegarbage{key:42}garbagegarbage[1,2,3]{id:0}garbage...
```

You seem to want a parser that skips over the garbage, and (lazily) yields a sequence of ASTs for each document. This *could* be considered to be an incremental parser in its most general sense. But you'd actually implement a loop like this:

```
while stream is not empty:
  try:
    yield parse_document(stream at current position)
  except:
    advance position in stream by 1 character or token
```

The `parse_docment` function would then be a conventional, non-incremental parser. There is a minor difficulty of ensuring that you have read enough of the input stream for a successful parse. How this can be handled depends on the type of parser you are using. Possibilities include growing a buffer on certain parse errors, or using lazy tokenization.

Lazy tokenization is probably the most elegant solution due to your input stream. Instead of having a lexer phase produce a fixed list of tokens, the parser would lazily request the next token from a lexer callback<sup>[1]</sup>. The lexer would then consume as much of the stream as needed. This way, the parser can only fail when the real end of the stream is reached, or when a real parse error occurred (i.e. we started parsing while still in garbage).

<sup>[1] a callback-driven lexer is a good idea in other contexts as well, because this can avoid some [problems with longest-token matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17773976/1521179).</sup>

If you know what kind of documents you are searching for, you can optimize the skipping to stop only at promising locations. E.g. a JSON document always begins with the character `{` or `[`. Therefore, garbage is any string that does not contain these characters.

Comment: Your pseudocode is actually what I've been doing, but I thought it was just an ugly hack.  The parser throws two kinds of exceptions (`NO_MATCH` and `UNDERFLOW`) which allow me to distinguish whether I should advance the stream position or wait for more input.

Comment: @Kevin: I use this too, with _some_ safety features, to handle incoming data from a network in a proprietary format. Nothing hacky about it!

Answer (score 5):

There isn't one specific name for a parser that does this. But I will highlight one algorithm that does this: [parsing with derivatives](http://matt.might.net/articles/parsing-with-derivatives/).

It consumes input, one token at a time. It will produce a parse forest at the end of input. Alternatively, you can also get the whole parse forest while in the middle of parsing (a *partial* parse).

Parsing with derivatives handles context-free grammars, and will produce a parse forest for ambiguous grammars.

It's an elegant theory, really, but is only in its infancy, and isn't widely deployed. Matt Might has a list of links to various implementations in Scala/Racket/etc.

The theory is easier to learn if you start with recognition with derivatives (that is, start with taking derivatives of *languages*, with the goal of recognizing some input to determine whether it's valid or not), and then alter the program to parse with derivatives (that is, change it so instead of taking derivatives of *languages*, it takes derivatives of *parsers*, and computes a parse forest).

Comment: Downvoter: could you please explain what was worthy of a downvote? If there's something I need to fix or improve, it sure would be nice to know.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, and I would not dream of downvoting without a
comment. But your enthousiastic paper has no reference to the many
existing parsers that achieve the same result, regarding complexity
and parse forest. Functional programming is great, but comparing a
result with the existing literature on the subject is nice too. How
convenient are your parse forest for further use?

Comment: @babou: for the record, I'm not the author of that blog/paper. But yes, I agree I could add more detail comparing this algorithm with others and explain it in detail. [Matt Might has a whole lecture on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzsK8Am6dKU), but it would be nice to consolidate it into this answer. If I get time I'll try to expand this answer.

Comment: Do not spend too much time on expanding it. As far as I can tell, that is not what the OP is after. His question requires careful reading. His use of parse forest is not yours. - - Regarding derivatives ... it sounds like it must be interesting, but one must relate it to previous work ... and there is a significant body of it. But I do not mean in this answer, but in the papers of M Might, or his blog.

Answer (score 2):

Far from ideal, but I've seen it done more than once: at each input line try to parse.  if fails, keep the line and add the next one.  In pseudocode:

```
buffer = ''
for each line from input:
    buffer = buffer + line
    if can parse buffer:
        emit tree
        buffer = ''
```

The big problem is that in some languages you can't know if an expression is complete before reading the next line.  In that case, you it seems that you could read the next one, and check if it's a valid beginning, or a valid continuation... But for that you need the exact language syntax

Worse, in those languages it's not hard to create a pathological case that can't be parsed until the end of file, even if it wasn't a single long statement.

Answer (score 0):

### In a nutshell

It seems that the fast solution to your problem is to define a REGEX,
or a FSA (finite state automaton), that recognizes all the possible
beginnings of documents (false positives are allowed, that would not
actually correspond to a document). You can then run it very fast on
your input to identify the next place where a document could start
with few errors. It may cause a few erroneous position for a document start, but they
will be recognized by the parser and abandonned.

So *Finite State Automaton* may be the parser name you were looking
for. :)

### The problem

It is always difficult to understand a practical problem, especially
when the vocabulary may have many interpretation. The word parse
forest was coined (afaik) for Context-Free (CF) parsing of ambiguous
sentences that have several parse-trees. It can be generalized
somewhat to parsing a lattice of sentences, or to other types of
grammar. Hence all the answers about Earley, GLR, Marpa and derivative
parsers (there are many others) that were not relevant in this case.

But that is apparently not what you have in mind. **You want to parse a
unique string that is a sequence of unambiguous documents, and get a
parse-tree for each**, or some kind of structured representation, since
you do not really say how the syntax of your documents is
defined, where it stand from a formal language point of view. What you have is
an algorithm and tables that will do the parsing job when started at
the beginning of a document. So be it.

**The actual problem is that your stream of document contains
considerable garbage that separates the documents.** And it seem that
your difficulty is to scan this garbage quickly enough. Your current
technique is to start at the beginning, and try to scan from the first
character, and skip to the restart at the next character whenever it
fails, until you get a whole document scanned. Then you repeat stating
from the first character after the document just scanned.

That is also the solution suggested by @amon in the second part of [his
answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260109/name-for-this-type-of-parser-or-why-it-doesnt-exist/260113#260113).

It may not be a very fast solution (I have no way to test),
because it is unlikely that the code of the parser is optimized to
be very efficiently started on the beginning of a document.  In
normal use it does this only once, so that it is not a hot spot from
an optimization point of view. Hence, your moderate happiness with this solution
is not too surprising.

So what **you really need is an algorithm that can quickly find the
beginning of a document that starts with a mass of garbage.** And you
are lucky: such algorithms do exist. And I am sure you know it: it is called searching for a REGEX.

### The simple solution

What you have to do is to analyze the specification of your documents
to find how these documents start. I cannot exactly tell you how, as I
am not sure how their syntax specification is organized
formally. Possibly they all start with some word from a finite list,
possibly mixed with some punctuation or numbers. That is for you to
check.

What you have to do is to define a finite state automaton (FSA), or
equivalently for most programmers a regular expression (REGEX) that
can recognize the first few characters of a document: the more, the
better, but it need not be very large (as that may take time and
space). This should be relatively easy to do from the specification of
your documents, and can probably be done automatically with a program
that reads the specification of your documents.

Once you have produced your regexp, you can run it on your input
stream to get very quickly to the beginning of your first (or next)
document as follows:

I assume:
- `docstart` is a regex that matches the beginning of all documents
- `search(regex, stream)` is a function that searches the `stream` for
  a substring that matches `regex`. When it returns, the stream is
  reduced to its suffix substream starting at the beginning of the
  first matching substring, or to the empty stream is no match is
  found.
- `parse(stream)` attempts to parse a document from the beginning of
  the stream (what is left of it), and returns the parse tree in
  whatever format, or fails. When it returns, the stream is reduced to
  its suffix substream starting at the position immediately following
  the end of the parsed document.  It calls an exception if the parse
  fails.

```
forest = empty_forest
search(docstart, stream)
while stream is not empty:
  try:
    forest = forest + parse(stream)
  except
    remove first character from stream
  search(docstart, stream)
```

Note that the removal of first character is necessary so that the next
search will not find again the same match.

Of course, shortening of the stream is an image. It may just be an
index on the stream.

A final note is that your regex does not need to be too accurate, as
long as it recognizes all beginnings. If it recognizes occasionally a
string that cannot be the beginning of a document (false positive),
then the only penalty is the cost of one useless call to the parser.

So that may possibly help simplifying the regex, if useful.

### About the possibility of a faster solution

The above solution should work pretty well in most cases. However, if
you have really a lot of garbage and terabytes of file to process,
there might be other algorithms that run faster.

The idea is derived from the [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). This
algorithm can search a stream for a single string extremely fast
because it uses a structural analysis of the string to skip reading
most of the stream, jumping over fragments without even looking at
them. It is the fastest searching algorithm for a single string.

Thr difficulty is that its adaptation to search regex, rather than a
single string, seems very delicate and might not work as well, depending on
the features of the regex you are considering. That might in turn
depend on the syntax of the documents you are parsing. But do not trust me too much on this since I did not have time to do a careful reading of the documents I found.

I am leaving you [with one](http://nothings.org/computer/source/sgrep.html) or [two pointers](http://www.drdobbs.com/combining-boyer-moore-string-search-with/184401244) I found on the web, including one that is apparently a [refereed research paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642303000133),
but you
should consider this as more speculative, possibly researchy, to be
considered only if you had strong performance problems. And there is
probably no of the shelf program that will do it.

Answer (score -2):

What you are describing can be described as SAX vs. SOM.

SAX - (Simple API for XML) is an event sequential access parser API developed by the XML-DEV mailing list for XML documents.

SOM - (XML Schema Object Model) random access to in memory representation of an XML file

There are implementations of both types in C#, and Java, and probably many more. Usually an XSD or DTD is optional.

The joy of SAX is that it is low memory overhead, which is great for large XML files. The trade off is that random access using SAX is either non-existent or slow, and worse the development time is usually considerable more than with SOM. The obvious problem with SOM is potentially large RAM requirements.

This answer is not applicable for all platforms and all languages.

Comment: Why do you think the OP is parsing XML?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Snowman Almost nothing so far was answering the question, including the first half of the accepted answer. No point in picking on anyone. The question needs careful reading.

Comment: @babou I was not picking on anyone, I was explaining my downvote.

Comment: @Snowman *explaining my downvote*. That is fair, and I do wish more users would do it. I am no native speaker: picking on him mays be too strong an expression. It is just that everyone has been making unwarranted assumptions. So it is not even worth noticing. It is true that this one seems a bit more off than the others.

Comment: No worries. My answer is in fact incorrect. As my brain was parsing the question it automatically inserted the acronym 'XML' when the 'parsing' token was encountered. In my defense I had been working with XSLT all day long.

Comment: while SAX and XML are not appropriate for this question the idea of an "event sequential access parser" does suggest a step towards what the OP is looking for.